# Accessing element in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Actually i am submitting one webpage which contains an element name observer and as "2".
Before submitting i am changing the value of element and then submitting the webpage.On submitting the same page will appear containing the changed value of element.Now when i am trying to access this element by its id it is not giving me the changed value but it is giving me empty string.

code for this

```
//for changing the value of element 
String a="muthu_snmp"; 
driver.findElement(By.id("2")).sendKeys(a); // working fine 
driver.findElement(By.id("submit")).click();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("2")));
String s=driver.findElement(By.id("2")).getText(); //this is giving me "" ie empty strings.
```

actually i want to compare that the value i have sent is saved or not.
so please help ...

Comment: did you check the resulting document by hand? How does the html look like for this element with id ="2" ?

Answer (score 0):

If your element is a text field, you must return its value. Read more [here](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getAttribute%28java.lang.String%29)

```
String s=driver.findElement(By.id("2")).getAttribute("value");
```